# How do I include CSS resource in programmatically generated HTML for iPhone UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, css, xcode, uiwebview

I am programmatically generating HTML and want to link to a CSS file that I've included in my Resources folder. I am using a baseURL of nil, and my CSS file is at the top level of the project file, but this "link" is definitely not working (ie, the CSS file is clearly not being loaded/found when the UIWebView displays the HTML).

Is it possible to do this? Or will I need to put the CSS file on the web somewhere and link to it via a URL?  (I can see the advantage of doing this -allowing the app to change its style without redistributing the app).

Thanks

Comment: What does the stylesheet reference line you're using look like?

Comment: Depending on how you're calling the stylesheet, [this article](http://www.jeremyflint.com/designing-for-the-iphone/) might help you. Post up the code your app is generating if you can.

Comment: Hi, I'm having this same issue, but the accepted answer actually makes nothing show on my UIWebView (the unstyled html displayed before adding the code).  Here is what my reference looks like:

NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><link id=\"stylesheet\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"Css/CommentStyle.css\" type=\"text/css\" /></head><body>%@</body></html>", htmlBody];

Any ideas? I will most likely open a new question, but figured I would use this one since it is the same problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks everyone! Here's what I did, works great.

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL *resourceBaseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[bundle bundlePath]];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:resourceBaseURL];
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the base URL to the bundle path:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[bundle bundlePath]];
```