# how to access local data from external webpage?

Tags: android, html, import, webview

I'm trying to access the data inside the assets/css from an external HTML file.

The process goes like this:

```
<html> 
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=yes" />  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<title>ola</title> 

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///android_asset/css/main.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///android_asset/css/sch.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/css/ethan.js" /> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/allinone.js" /> 

</head> 
<body> 
  <input id="btnTest1" name="button" type="button" style="height:0px;width:0px;" /> 
</body> 
</html>
```

So here the thing is that, I'm actually calling the HTML file using a link (since the HTML file is not locally present).  But `main.css`, `sch.css` and `ethan.js` are locally present in the assets/css folder.

What I'm trying to do is to load the `allinone.js` which is obviously external and the other three files into the which are internal and run the script.

I found "`file:///android_asset/css/main.css`" but it looks like it doesn't work.

Please help....

Answer (score 0):

I would be curious to know more about the use case here.  My understanding is this:

1. You're loading an externally hosted HTML file into an Android Webview
2. You need to overlay some local styles/scripts, which can't be hosted on the external site along with the HTML (presumably because you're generating them dynamically).

If that's so -- and given that the logical approach you conceived of using the file:// URI does not work -- there would seem to be two options, each making use of the webView API:

1. Load the HTML file from the remote source, modify it, then set it as the webView's source.  Locate the  tag of the remote HTML and inject your local  JS / CSS inline there.
2. Make use of the 'loadUrl' WebView method to inject your CSS/Javascript dynamically (this seems unnecessarily complicated if #1 is an option).  For example:

---

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:injectJavascript(js)");
```

where the parameter 'js' is some inline Javascript that you load within your Android code, and `injectJavascript` is a method in the remote HTML file that actually inserts it into your DOM.  Take an analogous approach to insert your CSS ...

Admittedly these approaches are a bit hackish.  Ideally you would use a custom method of the WebView class like 'addCssToDom' or something, but as far as I can see, no such methods are available.

Comment: Actually, before you try the above, you might want to explore the method 'loadDataWithBaseUrl' (with the base URL set to your local resources file://...).  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html.  This would appear to be exactly analogous to how someone solved a similar problem for iPhone (cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357878/how-do-i-include-css-resource-in-programmatically-generated-html-for-iphone-uiwe)